# Check if webview correctly loaded android

Tags: android, caching, webview

I want to display an alert when my webview has not loaded correctly. I already show an alert when connection fails, but I don't want to show that alert if the webview is loaded from the cache.
A solution could be to know if webview has loaded correctly from cache, but I don't know how to do that.
Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a full working solution, for all posible cases. It's based on save and retrieve the cache data manually. If I have my webview cached, I load it from where I've saved it. If not, I check internet connection and I save it in my "custom" cache (located in my app cache directory). Then, I only show the connection alert when I don't have my webview "cached" and I don't have internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this helps, However i use the follow code to display a alert dialog when a error is caught in my webview.

```
@Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
            String description, String failingUrl) {
        AlertDialog.Builder localBuilder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Webview_Main.this);
        localBuilder2.setTitle(R.string.webview_error_received_title);
        localBuilder2.setMessage(R.string.webview_error_received);
        localBuilder2.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        localBuilder2.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(
                    DialogInterface paramDialogInterface,
                    int paramInt) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        localBuilder2.show();
    };
```

Comment: The problem is that when I don't have internet connection but my webview is in cache, this code would return an alert, but the webview would be shown properly, and I want to avoid that alert to be shown... but thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found a hack, but I'd like to receive more posible solutions, because I'm sure it's not the best way.
I'm using "onScaleChanged" event to determine if the webview has loaded the image (in my case, I only load an image). That event is fired when it loads the image from Internet or from the cache, so if it's fired **with some special scale values**, it means the image hasn't been loaded. In some cases, depending on the image size and proportions, those values doesn't indicate if it is correctly loaded, but in most cases it does (and choosing the images proportions it works always correctly).

Comment: I will accept other answer if someone is able to make it work always and not only in some cases, with or without using "onScaleChanged". Thanks!